# Включение результата запроса

Tags: sql

Всем добрый день. Предположим у меня есть два sql запроса, каждый из которых возвращает последовательность целых чисел. Подскажите пожалуйста как мне определить, включает ли одна из них другую в себя целиком?

Comment: Проверить на not in (select -- 2-й запрос ... ). Если есть результат -- значит первый запрос не включается во второй полностью

Comment: спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 2):

Это называется [реляционным делением](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_relational_division.html).